What's the maximum probability of picking a black ball out of $30$ red and $30$ black balls?

$30$ red and $30$ black balls are distributed in two distinct boxes in such a way that for this given distribution, the probability of picking a black ball is maximum, given that picking any one of the two boxes is equally likely. Find the maximum probability.

My Attempt:
If we put all black balls in one box and all the red in the other then probability=$1/2*1+1/2*0=1/2$
If we put 15 red in one, 15 in other. 15 black in one, 15 in other then probability=$1/2*1/2+1/2*1/2=1/2$
If we put 10 red in one, 20 in other. 20 black in one, 10 in other then probability=$1/2(2/3+1/3)=1/2$
If we put all 60 balls in one, zero in other then probability=$1/2*1*2=1/4$
Just from these cases, can we say the answer is $1/2?$
Edit:
If one box has $x$ black balls and $y$ red balls, then the other box has $30-x$ black balls, $30-y$ red balls.
Therefore, probability of picking black ball= $\frac12\left(\frac x{x+y}+\frac{30-x}{60-(x+y)}\right)$
How to maximize it?

What if one box has a single black ball, and the other has $29$ black and $30$ red ones?

@JyrkiLahtonen you are awesome, thanks. $44/59$ was indeed one of the options.
